# jquery bind function with resize event AFTER function is loaded with a click event

Tags: jquery, function, resize

I have created a function that positions an element relatively with a click function.

After the function is run and the element is positioned, I want it to change accordingly on window resize/scroll.

How can this be achieved?

```
$('#mybtn').click(function(){
myfunction
}
```

I had no idea how to search about this, I even had trouble expaining it at the topic, so if there's an answer somewhere, please point me there.

Comment: If the element is placed relatively, you should not have to implement and handlers for scroll/resize if you want the element to be at the same place relatively. So my question is, what do you want to do with the newly placed element when the window scrolls/resizes?

Comment: The element being positioned has actually ABSOLUTE properties; think of it as a tooltip; you click on a button and position it under the element you click on. However, the button is in a fluid parent so it moves as you resize the screen and I want the tooltip to follow. edit: Now that I think about it, 'relatively' was probably the wrong selection of word. Sorry :/

Answer (score 0):

You can scroll to an element on view. Suppose that myElement is the DOM element to be positionned:

```
$('#mybtn').click(function(){
  myFunction2DoPosition();
  myElement.scrollIntoView(true);
}
```

Comment: This is not what I am looking for; There's a button inside a fluid parent. Resizing the screen moves the button position up and down, left and right; So, it's not scrolling but moving the element in its correct position under the trigger button.